# Express.js does not render handlebars but shows a empty page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-handlebars

I'm new in nodejs and express framework. I'm trying to create a login interface for test purpose, and i'm using a render engine called `handlebars` but i can't make to nodejs render handlebars, instead it just shows a empty page meaning it is not rendering anything.

I just reread the code about 5 times, but i can't find what is wrong. Please help me see what i can't see.

Note: i installed `express`, and `express-handlebars`

`app.js` **code:**

```
//Requiring Modules:

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000; //Port where server will be located
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');

//Code

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({
    layoutsDir: `${__dirname}/views/layouts`
}));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.render('main', {layout: 'index'});
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server on port: ${port}`);
});
```

The project folder contains **three main folders** and **three files**:

- **node_modules** (with nodejs modules)
- **public** (a public folder which is empty)
- **views** (where `.handlebars` files are located)

  - **layouts** (folder)

    - `index.handlebars` (handlebars file)
  - `main.handlebars` (handlebars file)
- `app.js` (main code)
- `package-lock.json`
- `package.json`

`index.handlebars` **code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

`main.handlebars` **code**:

```
<h1>This is a test</h1>
```

Sorry if i'm missing something very obvious, but i can't really see it.

**Note:** as the user below said, i tried changing index.handlebars content to see if the file render. The thing is that, index.handlebars doesn't recognize main.handlebars

[image: index.handlebars render]

Comment: What if you change index.handlebars - does it change anything? Just to understand if the template is being rendered at all

Comment: what do you mean changing index.handlebars?

Comment: tested and your exact code works fine https://replit.com/@lcherone/TealQueasyCrash#index.js